# Is this a 5*5 array after executing the dataframe function?

Tags: r, dataframe

In the spirit of experimenting I decided to take 5 lists to form components of a dataframe, during which I encountered the following result.

I took 5 lists separately to form a dataframe.

```
i=0:4
l1=list(1+5*i)
l2=list(l1[[1]]+1)
l3=list(l2[[1]]+1)
l4=list(l3[[1]]+1)
l5=list(l4[[1]]+1)
df <- data.frame(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5)
df

c.1..6..11..16..21. c.2..7..12..17..22.
1                   1                   2
2                   6                   7
3                  11                  12
4                  16                  17
5                  21                  22
  c.3..8..13..18..23. c.4..9..14..19..24.
1                   3                   4
2                   8                   9
3                  13                  14
4                  18                  19
5                  23                  24
  c.5..10..15..20..25.
1                    5
2                   10
3                   15
4                   20
5                   25
```

This was the output.

While I was expecting 1 to 25 in a 5 * 5 matrix with 1 to 5 in the first row and so on.So how did this result comeup? Also how can I get my expected result?

Comment: It looks like a regular `data.frame` column because `data.frame` is a `list` with columns having same length with some attributes.  It is the column names that you find `c 1...6..` Just change the column names with `names(df) <- paste0("V", 1:5)`

Comment: Thanks...I realized that was the case when I wrote it into a csv file.

Comment: Easy way to check the dimensions of a data frame if the printed output isn't clear: `dim(df)`